# OPTIONS http methods gives an empty response on Heroku

Tags: heroku, cors

When I do things locally my CORS calls are working fine

```
$ curl -i -X OPTIONS "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/login"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:9000
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 2
Set-Cookie: connect.sid=blablabla; Path=/; HttpOnly
Date: Wed, 02 Apr 2014 13:46:30 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

OK
```

But when I deploy and try the same on heroku it does not work anymore:

```
$ curl -i -X OPTIONS "http://<myapp>.herokuapp.com/api/v1/login"
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Any idea what that could be due to?

Comment: Is `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:9000` hardcoded?

Comment: No, it is not, it depends on the environment. This is set correctly and all other http method work. Just options is giving me trouble and only on the remote (heroku) server

Comment: Is the request reaching your app or is it failing during HTTP routing?

Comment: It does not appear in my app's logs. So does that mean that heroku's nginx is rejecting it? Why would it do that? The exact same program used to work a couple of month ago on heroku too

Comment: Not in logs means request never hit your app, and someone along the way rejected it. Heroku supports `OPTIONS` (as well as all the other exotic HTTP methods) so I'm not sure where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I filed a ticket for this, as it turned out, things were not easy to troubleshoot, but the answer is very simple: make your calls using https instead of http

Comment: I've just run into this as well, and I can't find any information about it online. Can you explain in more detail what you found out from filing the ticket? Seems like information that many others who are banging their head against this would find helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Getting no response might be caused by configuration similar to this:

```
if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|DELETE)$ ) {
    return 444;
}
```

Which means that nginx will close the connection without a proper response, that's why this is so difficult to debug.

**Search your configuration for the 444 return code.** If you find something like the above, just add `OPTIONS` to the list).