# Rails app on heroku stopped working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a rails app deployed on heroku. It worked for about a year. Lately I just can't enter the app. Connection takes too long. I tried to restart dynos but it has no effect. I have also changed from unicorn to puma.

After restart I have in logs

```
2016-01-20T21:15:06.007597+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2016-01-20T21:15:06.007619+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 2.15.3 (ruby 2.0.0-p648), codename: Autumn Arbor Airbrush
2016-01-20T21:15:06.007621+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2016-01-20T21:15:06.007622+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2016-01-20T21:15:09.455202+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-01-20T21:15:09.218059+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-01-20T21:15:08.018346 #3]  INFO -- : Loading Rails (4.2.5) integration
2016-01-20T21:15:09.218129+00:00 app[web.1]: appsignal: Starting AppSignal 0.11.7 on 2.0.0/x86_64-linux
2016-01-20T21:15:09.221967+00:00 app[web.1]: appsignal: Started Appsignal agent
2016-01-20T21:15:09.323110+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:48877
```

== EDIT: ==

After curl I get

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I have found here [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813645/options-http-methods-gives-an-empty-response-on-heroku) to use https instead of http, however from https curl I get

```
curl https://myapp.herokuapp.com
<html><body>You are being <a href="https://myapp.pl/">redirected</a>.</body></html>%
```

I have run out of ideas. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try curling the website and see what you get. Might be DNS resolution issue?

Comment: I have added curl results to question.

Comment: What is the url of your website?

Comment: katomed.pl, herokkuapp is by default I have added the redirection in heroku project settings a long time ago.

Comment: What do you mean herokuapp is by default? What sort of redirection did you set up? What is the original herokuapp url?

Comment: When you create application on heroku myapp.herokuapp.com is by default (in my case katomed.herokuapp.com). There in the settings tab you can redirect it to other domain. Acording to heroku .herokuapp.com is already with ssl - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turend out that server settings was the problem. I had a redirection to ip. Don't know how it had worked for so long. I have changed it for a CNAME record and it works like a charm.